# Spark Dataframe | Merge mulitple rows with missing values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe with a column that is a list of strings and another column that contains year.
There are a few rows with a missing values for the year column

---

| Year | fields |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | IFDSDEP.7 |
|  | IFDSDEP.7,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54,IFDSIMP.60 |
| 2020 | IFDSIMP.7,IFDSIMP.14,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54 |

I would like to merge rows with or without year value to a single row, is there a way to do it ?
In production, we can have multiple years and there could be a million rows.

My output should look like this:

---

| Year | fields |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | IFDSDEP.7,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54,IFDSIMP.60,IFDSIMP.14 |

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I do not understand well, you want to merge all your (million) rows (whatever the year) in a single row, and having a field column without any duplicates ? Can you describe the behavior you want for row without year ?

Comment: is there an id field that tracks the order of the records? without that spark will just merge randomly and a record meant for 2020 year might get merged with that of 2021

Comment: @Gregoire/@Samkart - I need to parse a set of PIG scripts, each script has fields belonging to a particular year. My end goal is to create a dataframe with two columns, year, and fields. All the fields belonging to a particular year should be in a single row.
Below is an example of the script
-----



data_2021_I = LOAD_DATA('$PARQUET_PATH');
criteria1_r1 = FILTER data_2021_I BY (field_map#'IFDSGEN.6'.$1.$0 < -236822400)
criteria1_result = FOREACH criteria1_r1 GENERATE re, CONCAT('{','"Key1":', '"', (field_map#'IFDSIMP.60'.$1.$0 is null ? '' : field_map#'IFDSIMP.60'.$1.$0),'"','}') ;

Comment: @Gregoire/@samkart - I'm using the below code to extract fields  

  val extractedFields = spark.sql("""
        |SELECT
        | REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(raw,"field_map#\'.*?\'", 0) AS extraction,
        | REGEXP_EXTRACT(raw,"data_\\d+", 0) AS yearField
        |FROM pigFields
        |""".stripMargin)  

  val uniqueArray = extractedFields.withColumn("uniqueFields", array_distinct($"extraction"))  

  val extractedFieldString = uniqueArray.withColumn("fieldStr", concat_ws(",", $"uniqueFields")).withColumn("YearStr", concat_ws(",", $"yearField"))

Comment: val extractedFieldsDF = extractedFieldString.withColumn("year", regexp_extract($"YearStr", "\\d+", 0)).withColumn("fields2", regexp_replace($"fieldStr", "field_map#'", "")).withColumn("fields", regexp_replace($"fields2", "'", "")).select($"year", $"fields").filter("fields <> ''")
val finalTbl = extractedFieldsDF.groupBy("year").agg(collect_list("fields")).alias("fieldId")

Answer (score 0):

If the fields column is a string you should probably first split this string into an array of strings, that way you will be able to combine into a unique list and then join them all back.

Regarding the nulls in the year column, you will have to fill the missing values. you will need to find a way to know which year to fill if there are multiple years.

Once you have done that, groupBy should do the trick.

```
# Your example DataFrame
df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    [2020, "IFDSDEP.7"],
    [None, "IFDSDEP.7,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54,IFDSIMP.60"],
    [2020, "IFDSIMP.7,IFDSIMP.14,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54"],
], schema=StructType([
    StructField("year", IntegerType()),
    StructField("fields", StringType())
])).cache()

df.show(truncate=False)
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|year|fields                                               |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|2020|IFDSDEP.7                                            |
|null|IFDSDEP.7,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54,IFDSIMP.60|
|2020|IFDSIMP.7,IFDSIMP.14,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+

# Replace null with 2020 for `year` column
df = df.fillna({"year": 2020})

df.show(truncate=False)
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|year|fields                                               |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+
|2020|IFDSDEP.7                                            |
|2020|IFDSDEP.7,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54,IFDSIMP.60|
|2020|IFDSIMP.7,IFDSIMP.14,IFDSIMP.51,IFDSIMP.52,IFDSIMP.54|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------+

# Transforming the fields column
df = df.withColumn("fields", F.split(F.col("fields"), ","))

df.show(truncate=False)
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|year|fields                                                     |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|2020|[IFDSDEP.7]                                                |
|2020|[IFDSDEP.7, IFDSIMP.51, IFDSIMP.52, IFDSIMP.54, IFDSIMP.60]|
|2020|[IFDSIMP.7, IFDSIMP.14, IFDSIMP.51, IFDSIMP.52, IFDSIMP.54]|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+

# Aggregate on year and collect all arrays of fields then combine them all and make them distinct
df_agg = df.groupby("year").agg(F.array_distinct(F.flatten(F.collect_list("fields"))))

df.show(truncate=False)
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|year|array_distinct(flatten(collect_list(fields)))                                     |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020|[IFDSDEP.7, IFDSIMP.51, IFDSIMP.52, IFDSIMP.54, IFDSIMP.60, IFDSIMP.7, IFDSIMP.14]|
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

breaking down the last part of the code:

**F.collect_list("fields")** - collect all the fields arrays for the group by key (year)
by now you should have an array of arrays

`[[IFDSDEP.7], [IFDSDEP.7, IFDSIMP.51, IFDSIMP.52, IFDSIMP.54, IFDSIMP.60], [IFDSIMP.7, IFDSIMP.14, IFDSIMP.51, IFDSIMP.52, IFDSIMP.54]]`

**F.flatten()** - this function flattens out the sub arrays into one large array

`[IFDSDEP.7, IFDSDEP.7, IFDSIMP.51, IFDSIMP.52, IFDSIMP.54, IFDSIMP.60, IFDSIMP.7, IFDSIMP.14, IFDSIMP.51, IFDSIMP.52, IFDSIMP.54]`

**F.array_distinct()** - this function deduplicates the values in the array which results in what you expect

`[IFDSDEP.7, IFDSIMP.51, IFDSIMP.52, IFDSIMP.54, IFDSIMP.60, IFDSIMP.7, IFDSIMP.14]`